# Fin rot, clamped fin, or what?

Tags: health, betta

I decided to save my betta from dying in an abandoned bowl. The previous owner kept him in a 1 gallon bowl that was never cleaned and at 68°.

I'm trying to rescue him. So now he's in a 5 gallon tank at 78° and much cleaner. However he is still sick and I'm not 100% sure what is wrong. He has more energy now and I'm guessing because of the warmer temperature, clearer tank, and more room but he's still stressed. I'm guessing his age may be related to his lower energy level too. I have no idea how old he is but his fins are needing some treatment.

His dorsal fin looks clamped and the tip is rotted away. Like ashy color. Looks like a piece of cooled ember. I'm sure there's probably multiple things wrong and I need know what I should do? [image]

Comment: please edit your question and give this information,the readings of your latest watertest ammonia-nitrite-ph.did you cycle the new tank properly before you added the fish https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm

Comment: the reason i ask about this information is to get an overviw of the situation(have the fish been exposed to toxins like ammonia or nitrite or is something else wrong in the environment)

Comment: In the bowl that he was originally in, I’m confident he was exposed to ammonia and nitrates and just everything bad. It was not clean. In that bowl is where his fins started to look bad so I transferred him to the 5 gallon tank. I cycled the tank beforehand using water conditioner and safe start to help cycle new aquariums. I waited 48 hours and I tested it with a strip. It says that everything looked ideal. This was a few days ago. I’m working on getting a pre-filter sponge for the filter nozzle to adjust the flow. Am I down the right path? What looks wrong exactly?

Comment: According to the chart I have it says the nitrate level is I'm guessing between 0-20 (safe), the nitrite is zero, pH I’m guessing between 7.2 and 7.8 and water temperature is at 77F